# Unable to Cover code for new custom object record creation

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Below is my apex class and test class to cover the same. I have tried to get 100% coverage, but stuck in the part where I'm creating instance of a custom object (Shown as red in the screenshot).

Apex  Class:-

```
public class NewDocuSignEnvelopeExtension{

    public NewDocuSignEnvelopeExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

    public NewDocuSignEnvelopeExtension() {

    }

    public dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c status{
        get{
            if(status == null)
                status = new dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c();
            return status;
        }set;}

    public String envelopeStatus {get;set;}

    public PageReference prepareDataForSave(){
        String opptyId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
        Boolean result = true;
        String missingDataError = '';

        if(envelopeStatus == 'Declined' && (status.dsfs__Declined_Reason__c == null || status.dsfs__Declined_Reason__c == ''))
        {
            missingDataError = 'The "Declined Reason" cannot be empty when "Envelope Status" is Declined';
            result = false;
        }
        else if((envelopeStatus == 'Sent' || envelopeStatus == 'Completed') && (status.dsfs__Declined_Reason__c != null))
        {
            missingDataError = 'The "Declined Reason" should be empty when "Envelope Status" is not Declined';
            result = false;
        }
        else if((envelopeStatus == 'Sent' || envelopeStatus == 'Completed') && (status.dsfs__Declined_Reason__c == null))
            result =true;

        if(result)
        {
            PageReference dsPage=saveDocuSignRecord();
            dsPage.setRedirect(true);
            return dsPage;
        }
        else
        {
            displayFeedback(ApexPages.Severity.Error, String.valueOf(missingDataError));
            missingDataError = '';
            PageReference dsPage = new PageReference('/apex/NewDocuSignEnvelope?scontrolCaching=1&id='+opptyId);
            dsPage.setRedirect(false);
            return dsPage;
        } 
    }

    private void displayFeedback(ApexPages.Severity msgType, String message){
        ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(msgType, message);
        ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
    }

    public PageReference saveDocuSignRecord(){
        String opptyId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
        Opportunity oppty = new Opportunity();
        Id recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Manual').getRecordTypeId();
        oppty=[select id, name, AccountId from Opportunity where id =: opptyId];
        dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c ds = new dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c();
        ds.dsfs__Sender__c = UserInfo.getName();
        ds.dsfs__Sender_Email__c = UserInfo.getUserEmail();
        ds.dsfs__Subject__c = 'Important eSignature Request from Bright House Networks';
        ds.Lightning_Abhi__Envelope_status__c = envelopeStatus;
        ds.Lightning_Abhi__Status_Date__c = status.Status_Date__c;
        ds.dsfs__Declined_Reason__c = status.dsfs__Declined_Reason__c;
        ds.dsfs__Company__c = oppty.AccountId;
        ds.dsfs__Opportunity__c = oppty.Id;
        ds.RecordTypeId = recordTypeId;
        insert ds;
        PageReference dsPage = new PageReference('/' + ds.id);
        dsPage.setRedirect(true);
        return dsPage;
    }
}
```

Test Class:-

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class NewDocuSignEnvelopeTest {
    static testMethod void NewDocuSignEnvelopeTest1(){
        NewDocuSignEnvelopeExtension ndsee = new NewDocuSignEnvelopeExtension();
        ndsee.envelopeStatus = 'Declined';
        ndsee.status.dsfs__Declined_Reason__c = '';
        PageReference pDFS = ndsee.prepareDataForSave();
    }
    static testMethod void NewDocuSignEnvelopeTest2(){
        NewDocuSignEnvelopeExtension ndsee = new NewDocuSignEnvelopeExtension();
        ndsee.envelopeStatus = 'Sent';
        ndsee.status.dsfs__Declined_Reason__c = 'testDeclined';
        PageReference pDFS = ndsee.prepareDataForSave();
    }
    static testMethod void NewDocuSignEnvelopeTest3(){
        NewDocuSignEnvelopeExtension ndsee = new NewDocuSignEnvelopeExtension();
        ndsee.envelopeStatus = 'Completed';
        ndsee.status.dsfs__Declined_Reason__c = null;
        PageReference pDFS = ndsee.prepareDataForSave();
        PageReference sDSR = ndsee.saveDocuSignRecord();
    }
}
```

[image: Uncovered Code]

Comment: Regardless of the code coverage I would suggest to take SeeAllData=true out. 
It's highly recommended by best practices to not use it. 

Related to the code coverage i'm not sure at 100% but can you verify the value on opptyId isn't null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
oppty=[select id, name, AccountId from Opportunity where id =: opptyId];
```

This line fails with a QueryException; there's no opportunity matching the Id you provided. Make sure that opptyId isn't null first, or catch the exception.

In your unit test, make sure you're setting the correct page parameters, and that you're constructing all the data you need to avoid live data dependencies.

## Example

```
static testMethod void NewDocuSignEnvelopeTest3(){
    Account acc = new Account(Name='Test');
    insert acc;
    Opportunty opp = new Opportunity(Name='ABC',AccountId=acc.Id,CloseDate=Date.today(),StageName='Prospecting');
    insert opp;
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id',opp.Id);
    NewDocuSignEnvelopeExtension ndsee = new NewDocuSignEnvelopeExtension();
    ndsee.envelopeStatus = 'Completed';
    ndsee.status.dsfs__Declined_Reason__c = null;
    PageReference pDFS = ndsee.prepareDataForSave();
    PageReference sDSR = ndsee.saveDocuSignRecord();
}
```